# Using preg_replace_callback to identify and manipulate latex code

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-replace-callback

I have latex + html code somewhere in the following form:

```
...some text1.... \[latex-code1\]....some text2....\[latex-code2\]....etc
```

Firstly I want to obtain the latex codes in an array codes[] to be able to send them to a server for rendering, so that

```
code[0]=latex-code1, code[1]=latex-code2, etc
```

Secondly, I want to modify this text so that it looks like:

```
...some text1.... <img src="root/1.png">....some text2....<img src="root/2.png">....etc
```

i.e, the i-th latex code fragment is replaced by the link to the i-th rendered image.

I have been trying to do this with preg_replace_callback and preg_match_all but being new to PHP haven't been able to make it work. Please advise.

Comment: Please show the code what you tried so far. What was the most successfull point so far? If it's too complicated, first start with matching only.

Comment: To get latex codes using preg_match_all, i did: 
$pattern='/(\[)(.*)(\])/';
preg_match_all($pattern,$content,$latex_codes, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
even this is not working as of now. I should be able to get all the latex codes in $latex_codes[1]

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for codez:

```
$html = '...some text1.... \[latex-code1\]....some text2....\[latex-code2\]....etc';

$codes = array();
$count = 0;
$replace = function($matches) use (&$codes, &$count) {
    list(, $codes[]) = $matches;
    return sprintf('<img src="root/%d.png">', ++$count);
};
$changed = preg_replace_callback('~\\\\\\[(.+?)\\\\\\]~', $replace, $html);

echo "Original: $html\n";
echo "Changed : $changed\n\nLatex Codes: ", print_r($codes, 1), "Count: ", $count;
```

I don't know at which part you've got the problems, if it's the regex pattern, you use characters inside your markers that needs heavy escaping: For PHP and PCRE, that's why there are so many slashes.

Another tricky part is the callback function because it needs to collect the codes as well as having a counter. It's done in the example with an anonymous function that has variable aliases / references in it's `use` clause. This makes the variables `$codes` and `$count` available inside the callback.

Comment: I think I was running into problems with the regex pattern. This really helped. Thanks!

Comment: Hi hakre, can you send me the equivalent version for the above code for a lower version of PHP. I think you are using anonymous function in $replace which is not being compiled by the php compiler on my server (bravehost)?

Comment: It needs PHP 5.3, right. To do this in PHP 5.2, you need to encapsulate the callback into a class function to be able to have the  `$codes` and `$count` variables available.